# Can’t access router settings after accidentally disabling dhcp server

Tags: ubuntu, router, internet, dhcp

I had configured my raspberry pi server as a dns override in my router settings with dhcp server enabled. I accidentally disabled the dhcp server instead of the dns override and applied the settings. I lost connection to the internet on all devices and haven’t been able to access the router settings since. I receive the following message when I try : “This page is loading, please wait for a moment”.

I’ve reset the router and also tried setting my ipv4 settings manually to try to reconnect to router settings with no success.

Running ubuntu 19.10 but also have access to windows machine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Manually set the IP, Netmask, and possibly gateway under the Network Adapter's settings, then you'll be able to access the router's WebUI.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Where do I find what values to populate the up, netmask, and gateway with? Do I use what my Pi’s IP was for dns since I had override enabled and pointed to it? Thanks for your help

Comment: If you're trying to access the router, manually assign an IP and netmask within the same subnet the router is configured with (i.e. if router is `192.168.1.1/24`, set IP to a non-assigned IP, such as `192.168.1.254/24`; if you need to set a gateway as well, it will be the router's IP.)